# How to select all files of a given filetype EXCEPT ones matching a name pattern?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to select all files of a certain type in a given directory EXCEPT ones beginning with certain names. Why didn't this code work?

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\wdennis> Get-Item -Path ($AppDir + "reports\*.dbf") | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "reports*" -or "category*"}

    Directory: C:\Program Files\Application\reports

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-----          1/4/2007   9:37 AM       4842 category.dbf                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-----          9/7/2007   1:53 PM      43903 reports.dbf
```

I'm pretty new to PS, and very tired to boot, so maybe that's why I'm not understanding why this didn't work. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `-eq` and `-ne` match the given string and don't support wildcards.

Only `-like` supports wildcards for pattern matching.

You can however use a regular expression with the `-notmatch` switch to achieve what you want. Since it's a regular expression now you need to use `.*` instead of `*`. And the beginning is marked with `^`.

So you end with this

```
{$_.Name -notmatch "^reports.*|^category.*"}
```

The whole command

```
Get-Item -Path ($AppDir + "reports\*.dbf") | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^reports.*|^category.*"}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted... Thanks!